# More elegant way to select default values in LUA and avoid "attempt to index field 'x' (a nil value)"

Tags: parameters, lua, default

So I pass a parameter which has fields. Some fields it will always have, others it may not.

E.g.

```
field = {
  Name  ={  x=0.9833, y=2, h=0.2, w=3.12, f="Times Roman"},
  Suite ={  x=0.6933, y=1.74, h=0.2, w=0.5867}
}

function do_it_with(parm)
  local height=parm.h -- never fails
  local font=parm.f -- errors out if f not specified. 
-- more stuff --
  end

do_it_with(field.Name) -- just fine
do_it_with(field.Suite) -- "attempt to index field 'f' (a nil value)"
```

Which I don't understand. First, why can't font just become nil? And second, I thought I could just do

```
local font=parm.f or "Arial"
```

But that seems to be failing with the same error. So now I'm doing

```
if (type(field.f) ~= "string") then field.f = "Arial" end
```

which works, but it's /ugly/

Comment: The error message says you're trying to index `f`, which is not shown in the code you posted. The error must be elsewhere in the `do_it_with` function.

Comment: I'm very confused by this statement. f is referenced in the code right here:
    local font=parm.f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine as is:

```
field = {
  Name  ={ h=0.2, f="Times Roman"},
  Suite ={ h=0.2, }
}

function do_it_with(parm)
  local height = parm.h
  local font = parm.f
  print('height:', height, 'font:', font)
end

do_it_with(field.Name) 
do_it_with(field.Suite)
```

prints

```
height: 0.2 font:   Times Roman
height: 0.2 font:   nil
```

so your error is elsewhere in your code. There is also nothing wrong with:

```
local font=parm.f or "Arial"
```

Making this change in the above example shows "font:   Arial" instead of "font:   nil". So your final solution is not only not pretty (good for you for finding a workaround), it is unnecessary.

Print the exact error message (traceback) with line number info and mark the line where the error is flagged in your question.

Update: if you are using a custom version of Lua (say as part of an application), you should probably be able to do

```
local font
if parm['f'] == nil then parm.f = "Arial" end
```

It it still better than testing if type is string.

Comment: I think it may be something in my environment. When I try the same code from the command line, it works. In the system the code is running inside (and no, I can't share that) it fails. The error is certainly called out on that specific line, but something strange is going on with LUA. Is there a setting that would make LUA not allow the parm.f or "Arial" pattern?

Comment: @JamesNewton A customized version of Lua. Then all bets are off. I have added an update which to me is better than the string test you had.

Comment: Nice update... It also works perfectly on the command line and fails in this environment. Same error message. Checking type is the only thing that seems to work.

Comment: @JamesNewton How is that possible. Does parm have a metatable? You sure you are running the same script in the environment as on command line? So if after `local font` you write `print(parm, parm['f'])` what happens? Also thanks but you shouldn't accept the answer if it doesn't solve (or help solve) the issue...

Comment: I think the metatable for parm prevents any reference to anything that isn't there, e.g. has been customized in this environment to error out if you try. type checking catches that error and returns nil. And understanding why I wasn't getting the same result as others in LUA programming does solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

There must be some place in `do_it_with` that tries `parm.f.whatever` instead of `font.whatever`, or some other place in the code with the same construct. Try searching in for `.f.` in your editor.

The `parm.f or "Arial"` construct is indeed a useful and usual idiom for getting a default value.

Comment: ? I'm sorry, that really doesn't make any sense to me at all. there is no .whatever under f. f is a string value in some cases e.g. "Times Roman" and f does not exist (nil) in other cases. f is referenced in the code in the line local font=parm.f